# Strong deformation retraction $\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{B}^l \longrightarrow \{1\}\!\times\!\mathbb{B}^l\cup \mathbb{I}\!\times\!\{0\}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In Shastri's *[Elements of Differential Topology](http://books.google.si/books/about/Elements_of_Differential_Topology.html?id=DlUVQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)*, p. 225, there is written:

[image]

I don't understand this map $R$. Why is $\theta\!\in\!\mathbb{S}^{l-1}$, shouldn't we have $\theta\!\in\!\mathbb{B}^l$? Furthermore, how do I construct such a map myself? I see that the idea is for each $(s,x)\!\in\!\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{B}^l$ to construct a ray starting in $(0,\frac{x}{\|x\|})\!\in\!\{0\}\!\times\!\mathbb{S}^{l-1}$ and going through $(s,x)$, i.e. the ray 
$$\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\![0,\infty)\!\rightarrow\!\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{B}^l,\;\; (s,x,t)\mapsto
\begin{cases} 
(0,\frac{x}{\|x\|})+t\big((s,x)-(0,\frac{x}{\|x\|})\big)& x\!\neq\!0\\
(s,x) & x\!=\!0
\end{cases},$$
and then for each $(s,x)$ to choose the right $t_0\!\in\![0,\infty)$ where that ray hits $\{1\}\!\times\!\mathbb{B}^l\cup \mathbb{I}\!\times\!\{0\}$, divide that ray by $t_0$ so that the ray becomes a line parametrized by $\mathbb{I}$. I do not see a way to do this.

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^{l-1}$ is the boundary of the disc $\mathbb{D}^l$. You can consider a point in the disc as a pair $(\theta,s)$, with $0\leq s\leq 1$.

Comment: Ok, so $\theta\!=\!\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. But how did he get the formula for $R$?

Comment: Considering $r$ as the time, I guess that for $0\leq r\leq 1/2$, it sends the disc $\{r\}\times \mathbb{D}^l$ to a point on the segment $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ at time $2r$, i.e. $\{2r\}\times \{0\}$, and for the other half $1/2\leq r\leq 1$ it sends $\{r\}\times \mathbb{D}^l$ onto the discs $\{1\}\times \mathbb{D}^l_\rho$, where $\rho$ is related to the radius of the disc (starting with the disc with radius 0, i.e. the point $\{1\}\times \{0\}$ and ending with the disc with radius 1, i.e. $\{1\}\times \mathbb{D}^l$).

Comment: Roughly speaking, during the first half you collapse over the vertical segment and during the last half you project over the top concentric (from the center to the boundary) discs.

Comment: @LeonLampret I have been told that in algebraic topology it is common practice not to write down explicit formulas for deformation retracts/homotopies/etc. For example, if you look in Hatcher many deformation retracts are presented as pictures. For me I have to the point that if you show me the picture, I will accept it as my deformation retract....

Comment: Rather than trying to decipher the formula given (these usually sacrifice clarity for brevity, not splitting cases etc.), you can try to write down a geometrically simpler deformation retraction. For example, it should be relatively easy to write down the map that during $0\leq t\leq 1/2$ squeezes the bottom half of the cylinder onto the middle axis, producing a cone with a line segment attached, and during $1/2 \leq t\leq 1$ pushes the cone into the final shape by doing the standard "cornering" on each radial slice.

Comment: @Miha: Hmm, is there a nice way to strongly deformation retract $\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{I}$ onto $\{0\}\!\times\!\mathbb{I} \cup \mathbb{I}\!\times\!\{0\}$?

Comment: @Leon I don't know how nice it is, but there is the standard way, projecting from, say, the point (2,2) onto the union of the two line segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Turns out I misunderstood what the text was suggesting.

**Claim:** *$\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\!\mathbb{I}$ strongly deformation retracts onto $\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\!\{1\} \cup \{0\}\!\times\!\mathbb{I}$, and $\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\!\{0\}$ goes to $(0,0)$.*

**Proof:** Each element of $\mathbb{B}^k$ is written in polar coordinates as $(\theta,r)\in\mathbb{S}^{k-1}\!\!\times\!\mathbb{I}$, since $\frac{\mathbb{S}^{k-1}\!\times\mathbb{I}}{\mathbb{S}^{k-1}\!\times\{0\}}\approx\mathbb{B}^k$. The strong deformation retraction $h$ is obtained by not changing $\theta$ (i.e. $h$ is the same on each slice $\{(\theta,r,s)\!\in\!\mathbb{S}^{k-1}\!\!\times\!\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{I};\,\theta\!=\!\text{const.}\}\!\approx\!\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{I}$), on the lower half of the cylinder, $\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\![0,\frac{1}{2}]$, the outer line $\{(\theta_0,1)\} \!\times\! [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ is pushed to the middle line $\{(\theta_0,0)\} \!\times\! [0,1]$, on the upper half of the cylinder, $\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\![\frac{1}{2},1]$, the outer line $[\frac{1}{2},1] \!\times\!\{(\theta_0,1)\}$ is pushed to the top radial line$\{\theta_0\}\!\times\mathbb{I}\times\!\{1\}$, where the point $(1,\theta_0,1)$ does not move. Let us write $(r,s)$ instead of $(\theta_0,r,s)$. For $0\!\leq\!s\!\leq\!\frac{1}{2}$ the point $(1,s)$ therefore travels to $(0,2s)$, i.e. we have a straight path $t \mapsto (1,s) + t\big((0,2s)\!-\! (1,s)\big) \!=\!\big(1\!-\!t, s(1\!+\!t)\big)$. For $\frac{1}{2}\!\leq\!s\!\leq\!1$ the point $(1,s)$ travels to $(2(s\!-\!\frac{1}{2}),1)$, i.e. we have a path $t \mapsto (1,s) +t\big((2s\!-\!1,1) \!-\!(1,s)\big) \!=\!\big(1\!+\!2t(s\!-\!1),s\!+\!t(1\!-\!s)\big)$. Let us construct the homotopy for the remaining points as well (those from the whole square $\mathbb{I}\!\times\!\mathbb{I}$). The interval $0\!\leq\!s\!\leq\!\frac{1}{2}\!+\!\frac{1-r}{2} \!=\!\frac{2-r}{2}$ will be mapped at the end of the homotopy to $0\!\leq\!s\!\leq\!1$, hence each point $(r,s)$ travels to $(0,\frac{2}{2-r}s)$, i.e. we have a path $t \mapsto (r,s) +t\big((0,\frac{2}{2-r}s)\!-\! (r,s)\big) \!=\!\big(r\!-\!rt,s\!+\!t(\frac{2}{2-r}s\!-\!s)\big) \!=\!\big(r(1\!-\!t),s\!+\!st\frac{r}{2-r}\big)$. Now we must deal with the remaining points $(r,s)$  from the triangle  $\frac{2-r}{2}\!\leq\!s\!\leq\!1$. The line  through $(0,1)$ and $(1,\frac{1}{2})$ is $y\!-\!1\!=\!\frac{1/2-1}{1-0}(x\!-\!0)$, i.e. $y\!=\!-\frac{1}{2}x\!+\!1$. The line through $(1,1)$ in $(r,s)$ is $y\!-\!1\!=\!\frac{s-1}{r-1}(x\!-\!1)$. These two lines intersect in $(\frac{2s-2}{r+2s-3},\frac{r+s-2}{r+2s-3})$. The ratio of the distances is $\|-(1,1)\!+\!(r,s)\| \,/\, \|-(1,1)\!+\!(\frac{2s-2}{r+2s-3}, \frac{r+s-2}{r+2s-3})\|\!=\!\ldots\!=\!|r\!+\!2s\!-\!3|\!=\!3\!-\!r\!-\!2s\in[0,1]$. Therefore the point $(r,s)$ is mapped to $\big(1\!-\!(3\!-\!r\!-\!2s),1\big)\!=\! (r\!+\!2s\!-\!2,1)$, i.e. we have a path $t\mapsto (r,s)\!+\!t\big( (r\!+\!2s\!-\!2,1) \!-\!(r,s)\big) \!=\!\big(r\!+\!2t(s\!-\!1),s\!+\!t(1\!-\!s)\big)$. The desired strong deformation retraction is therefore

$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;h\!:\;\;\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\!\mathbb{I}\! \times\!\mathbb{I}\!\longrightarrow\!\mathbb{B}^l\!\times\!\mathbb{I},\;\;\; (\theta,r,s,t)\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
   \displaystyle \big(\theta,r(1\!-\!t),s\!+\!st{\textstyle\frac{r}{2-r}})\big) 
   & \hspace{-8pt} ;\;\; \displaystyle r\!+\!2s\!\leq\!2,\\
   \displaystyle \big(\theta,r\!+\!2t(s\!-\!1),s\!+\!t(1\!-\!s)\big) 
   &\hspace{-8pt} ;\;\; \displaystyle r\!+\!2s\!\geq\!2. \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\blacksquare
\end{cases}$$